# The type 'System.Boolean[,]' is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

У меня есть метод, который генерирует двумерный массив, который отправляется клиенту, если был запрос. Происходит 500 ошибка:The type 'System.Boolean[,]' is not supported. Я так понимаю, что что-то не так с методом, который заполняет массив. Как это можно исправить?

Метод:

```
public bool[,] FillArray()
{
    int _maxMines = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            
            switch (i)
            {
                case var x when x<5 && _maxMines >2:
                    _stairs[i, j] = true;
                    break;
                case var x when x>5 && _maxMines > 3 :
                    _stairs[i, j] = true;
                    break;
                case var x when x>9 && _maxMines > 4 :
                    _stairs[i, j] = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    _stairs[i, j] = _rnd.Next(2) == 1;
                    _maxMines++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return _stairs;
}
```

Comment: Используйте зубчатый массив `[][]` вместо двухмерного `[,]`, либо надо контракт сериализатору писать. Кстати, зачем возвращаемое значение, если массив объявлен за пределами метода? Только больше запутаетесь. Либо создавайте массив в методе, либо передавайте в метод аргументом, но не через поле. Либо метод `void`. Возвращать то что и так доступно через поле бессмысленно.

Comment: @aepot Благодарю вас за правильный ответ и за указанные недочеты.